# Helix Carousel not working in joomla

Tags: html, joomla, joomla3.0, helix

I use Shaper Helix 2 in my template, and I try to create the carousel. I use Joomla version 3.2, and use CustomHTML to create the carousel. But I do not know why it does not recognize as HTML, and it actually recognize as Text.

So in my home screen, the carousel show the code:
[carousel]
[carousel_item]add image here [caption]Powerful templates framework to develop Joomla base website faster![/caption][/carousel_item]
[/carousel]

not the actual carousel text.

How to solve this? Thank you very much. Appreciate a lot for someone help.

Comment: You should contact the developers of the Helix framework and read their forum and documentation to see if your question has already been answered.

Answer (score 5):

While in the Module Manager menu, go to the Options tab of your Module Custom HTML item and click Prepare Content -- Yes. Then Save. Voila!﻿